# Display multiple images with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, html

I have this PHP script that returns pictures from the database. I am using a loop now to return 5 pictures at once, but I think they are all overlapping so I am only seeing one. How can I shift each picture a couple of pixels over so I can see the other pictures?

```
<?php
    $mysqli=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','draftdb');
    if (!$mysqli)
    die("Can't connect to MySQL: ".mysqli_connect_error());

    $param = isset($_GET['rarity']) ? $_GET['loopcount'] :null;

    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT display.PICTURE_ID 
    FROM cards  
    INNER JOIN display ON cards.DISPLAY_ID = display.DISPLAY_ID 
    WHERE display.DISPLAY_ID=? AND cards.CARD_TYPE =?" );

    $cardtype='Rare';


    for ($i=0; $i<=5; $i++) 
    {
      $num[$i] = rand(16,30);
       for ($j=0; $j<$i; $j++) 
       {            
          while ($num[$j] == $num[$i])
          {              
             $num[$i] = rand(16,30);   
          }          

                   $displayid= array_shift($num);   

       }   



    $stmt->bind_param("si", $displayid, $cardtype);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($image);
    $stmt->fetch();
    header("Content-Type: image/jpeg");
    echo $image; 
    }


    ?>
```

Comment: Maybe because you sent a header? `header("Content-Type: image/jpeg");`

Comment: Probably `$stmt->bind_param("si", $displayid, $cardtype);` is wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't "display" an image with php. You do that with HTML using the `<img>` tag. What you do is printing the raw image data and then telling the browser It's a picture. I'm not sure what's gonna happen if you do this and print multiple images, but It's up to the browser how It should handle this probably.

This is sometimes done with *one* image if you for example store them as blobs in a database. But not for this purpose of displaying them.

If you want to merge images you can do this with the GD library in PHP.

Comment: It's displaying the picture I was just wondering how and if I can display more than 1 picture with the loop and offset them by a set number of pixels so I can see all of them.

Comment: That's what I'm telling you you cant, you can't tell the browser how to display things with PHP. Why are you not doing this with HTML?

Comment: You're right I was using PHP because I didn't think you could use programming logic in html, but I forgot about <script> ~_~.

Answer (score 2):

You can only send one picture to the browser with `Content-Type: image/jpeg`. I can think of two ways to send multiple pictures.

1.Use [GD](http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php) to make a new picture containing all of the other pictures and send it.

2.Send an HTML page instead of the picture:

```
<?php 
//some code which gets the images and puts them in an array - $images
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<body>
<?php foreach($images as $image):?>
    <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,<?php echo base64_encode($image);?>"/><br/>
<?php endforeach;?>
</body>
</html>
```

edit: It seems browsers have difficulty parsing very large HTML documents fast, so if you have large or lots of images it might be better to load them in separate HTTP requests (`src="image.php?image=xxxx"`).

Comment: Another solution that's common is having a PHP file that sends an image header and prints the data, given an image id. Pretty ugly to print the image data straight into the document imo, as images can be pretty big.

Comment: This is the simplest possible way i can think of for displaying several images. And since browsers don't really care about how pretty your HTML looks and more importantly caching in both cases will be the same I can't see a reason why doing it with n+1 HTTP requests would be better.

Comment: You are obviously right about the browser not caring about how the code looks like. Although I do believe this effects the client in at least one way, the htmldocument gets huge if you have many (or even just one) image. I just don't think htmldocuments should contain image data, even if its server generated.

Comment: I did a test with a 5MB bmp image on localhost and it takes 1-2 seconds to parse the HTML document (which is a LOT). The same image loaded directly with a separate HTTP request takes about 0.3 seconds. So if the image is big it is not a very good idea to load it inside HTML documents.